# How can I ask for user location the way google maps does it?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, userlocation

If I go to the google maps homepage, there's a button there with my location. If I press it, the browser asks me if I want to share my location with google. I know of the V3 API's `google.loader.ClientLocation`, but this isn't asking me anything related to location sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Geolocation.

The key piece of code you need to use is:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
```

It can take an errorCallback as an optional second parameter.